# android - Display data from database that has specific login id?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in android. I am working on passwordsaver app that have two table. First table is data that show title, email and password. Second table is user that add new user and then they can login.

I want to show each user specific data of  title, email and password according to his id ?

**Code**

```
public class Constants
{
    //id
    static final String ROW_ID="id";
    private static final String ROW_ID_USER="u_id";

    //COLUMNS USER
    static final String USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    static final String USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    //COLUMNS Data
    static final String TITLE = "title";
    static final String EMAIL = "email";
    static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    //DB NAME & Version
    static final String DB_NAME="my_DB";
    static final int DB_VERSION='3';

    //TABLE USER
    static final String TB_NAME_USER="u_TB";

    //TABLE DATA
    static final String TB_NAME="d_TB";

    //CREATING USER TABLE
    static final String CREATE_TB= "CREATE TABLE "
            + TB_NAME + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + TITLE + " TEXT, " + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + ROW_ID_USER + " INT, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(" + ROW_ID_USER + ") REFERENCES "
            + TB_NAME_USER + "(id) " + ")";

    static final String CREATE_TB_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TB_NAME_USER + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT "
            + ")";

    //INSERT for data
    public long add(String title, String email, String pass)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Constants.TITLE, title);
            cv.put(Constants.EMAIL,email);
            cv.put(Constants.PASSWORD,pass);

            return db.insert(Constants.TB_NAME,Constants.ROW_ID,cv);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    //update for data
    public long UPDATE(int id, String email, String pass)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Constants.EMAIL,email);
            cv.put(Constants.PASSWORD, pass);
            return db.update(Constants.TB_NAME,cv,Constants.ROW_ID+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //newUserSignUp
    public long insert(String email,String password)
    {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(Constants.USER_EMAIL, email);
        contentValue.put(Constants.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        long id = db.insert(Constants.TB_NAME_USER, Constants.ROW_ID, contentValue);
        return id;
    }

    //deleteData
    public boolean delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            int res = db.delete(Constants.TB_NAME,Constants.ROW_ID+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
            if (res>0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //RETRIEVE Data
    public Cursor getAllPlayers()
    {
        String[] columns={Constants.ROW_ID,Constants.TITLE,Constants.EMAIL,Constants.PASSWORD};

        return db.query(Constants.TB_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    //getSigleEntry for User Login
    public String getSingleEntry(String  email)
    {
        String[] selectionArgs ={email};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TB_NAME_USER,null,Constants.USER_EMAIL + " =?",selectionArgs,null,null,null,null);

        if (cursor.getCount()<1)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.USER_PASSWORD));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
  static final String CREATE_TB= "CREATE TABLE "
        + TB_NAME + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + TITLE + " TEXT, " + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
        + PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + "user_id" + " INT, "
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + "user_id" + ") REFERENCES "
        + TB_NAME_USER + "("+ROW_ID_USER+"));";

static final String CREATE_TB_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TB_NAME_USER + "(" + ROW_ID_USER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT "
        + ")";
```

}

when you insert into table data you also pass id like this

```
public long add(String title, String email, String pass,long id)
{
    try
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Constants.TITLE, title);
        cv.put(Constants.EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(Constants.PASSWORD,pass);
        cv.put("user_id",id);

        return db.insert(Constants.TB_NAME,null,cv);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Get data according to u_id used this query and pass id

```
 public Cursor getAllPlayers(long id)
{
    String[] columns={Constants.ROW_ID,Constants.TITLE,Constants.EMAIL,Constants.PASSWORD};
    String[] selectionArgs={String.valueOf(id)};

        return db.query(Constants.TB_NAME,columns,"user_id" + " =?",selectionArgs,null,null,Constants.ROW_ID+" Desc");

}
```

Comment: oops i cannot like your post because they show like this message Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15

Comment: You should mark his question so others know it has been solved.